# cumulative sum not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the cumulative sum for an entire column. Below is a sample of my data.

```
DT                             ETB_DT
Friday 00:00:00.0000000 Friday 04:00:00.0000000
Friday 00:00:00.0000000 Friday 08:00:00.0000000
Friday 00:00:00.0000000 Friday 12:00:00.0000000
Friday 00:00:00.0000000 Friday 16:00:00.0000000
Friday 00:00:00.0000000 Friday 20:00:00.0000000

No_of_records   
22             
41  
86  
65  
25
```

I have used the following code to get the cumulative column which is supposed to add on to the previous row.

```sql
Select *
       ,cumulative = sum(No_of_records) 
 From  withoutcumulative4
 group by DT,ETB_DT,No_of_records
  Order by DT
```

However, this gives me the following output.

```
DT                             ETB_DT
Friday 00:00:00.0000000 Friday 04:00:00.0000000
Friday 00:00:00.0000000 Friday 08:00:00.0000000
Friday 00:00:00.0000000 Friday 12:00:00.0000000
Friday 00:00:00.0000000 Friday 16:00:00.0000000
Friday 00:00:00.0000000 Friday 20:00:00.0000000

No_of_records   cumulative
22                  22
41                  41
86                  86
65                  65
25                  25
```

Below is my desired output.

```
DT                             ETB_DT
Friday 00:00:00.0000000 Friday 04:00:00.0000000
Friday 00:00:00.0000000 Friday 08:00:00.0000000
Friday 00:00:00.0000000 Friday 12:00:00.0000000
Friday 00:00:00.0000000 Friday 16:00:00.0000000
Friday 00:00:00.0000000 Friday 20:00:00.0000000

No_of_records   cumulative
22                  22
41                  63
86                  149
65                  214
25                  239
```

Do any of you have ideas? Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the syntax for cumulative sum:

```
Select DT, ETB_DT, No_of_records
       sum(No_of_records) over (order by DT, ETB_DT) as cumulative
From withoutcumulative4
Order by DT;
```

The `over` clause with `order by` is what makes the sum cumulative.  Not assigning it a name.

From what I can tell, you don't need `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use over:

```
Select *
       ,cumulative = sum(No_of_records) over (order by ETB_DT) 
 From  withoutcumulative4
  Order by DT
```